# googleVis, knitr, Rpubs, replicating example, knitr option?

Tags: r, google-visualization, knitr

Rookie question, I think.

I'm just trying to replicate this:

http://rpubs.com/gallery/googleVis

Open a new markdown document (in Rstudio), paste:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(googleVis))
T <- gvisTable(Exports, options = list(width = 200, height = 280))
G <- gvisGeoChart(Exports, locationvar = "Country", colorvar = "Profit", 
    options = list(width = 360, height = 280, dataMode = "regions"))
TG <- gvisMerge(T, G, horizontal = TRUE, tableOptions = "bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\" cellspacing=10")

print(TG, "chart")
```

Between the ```{r} tags.

The resulting output (from the print function) is just the javascript (I think) code. It's not actually drawing the plot, in the preview window or the online version after publishing.

Is something else needed in the markdown? Like:

```{r something=something}

To get it to interpret the output from the print command properly?

Thanks

**ANSWER**

```{r anythingyoulike, results='asis'}

The top of this post 
http://rpubs.com/gallery/googleVis really should point that out imo...

Comment: It might be worth noting that when it prints the javascript to page it has ## in front of it all. I've tried setting comment="" to get rid of that but no joy.

Comment: I just checked that page and it seems they did mention `results='asis'` there. The footer said the page was updated 11 days ago, so it seems you missed the first paragraph?

Comment: Cheers for all your work in this area of R Yihui :) I guess the 'updated date' thing is wrong haha, Josh from Rstudio updated it about 48 hours ago after I posted on their board, probably why the sentence starts with 'Also...' http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/676-gvismotionchart-and-rpubs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like ```{r results='asis'}. However I don't have knitr manual with me now so you need to check.

Comment: Have had a play with that and no joy yet. I am still looking around/trying things though. Thanks for the suggestion. See comment on question.

Comment: Okay, so it was results='asis' [have updated your answer to say results= not result=] my mistake for not checking the help closer, normally you get an error if you're off by a letter (the last s) >_< props to @BDiggs for spotting my mistake in chat